# A fast solution of $\frac{\left|x^2-1\right|-3}{1-2x}<\:x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have this easy inequality

$$\frac{|x^2-1|-3}{1-2x}<\:x$$

your solutions, step by steps are $]-1,\frac{1}{2}[\,\cup\, ]\frac{4}{3},+\infty[$, considering the signs of $|x^2-1|$, i.e. $x^2-1\geq 0 \iff x\leq 1 \vee x\geq 1$ and $x^2-1<0 \iff -1<x<1$ and solving a simple fracture inequality with $1-2x\neq 0$.

I have five options:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  A=]- 1; 1[\,\cup \,] \frac{4}{3} ; 2[ \\ \hline B=] -\infty;-1[ \cup ] \frac{1}{2} ; \frac{4}{3} [ \\ \hline C=]-1;\frac{1}{2}[ \cup ]  ; ]\frac{4}{3} +\infty[  \\ \hline D=] -\infty;-1[ \cup [1; \frac{4}{3} [ \\ \hline \text{None of the previous answers are correct}\\ \hline  \end{array}
I've seen, without to do the calculus, that the $0$ satisfies the inequality and it is not are into the sets $B$ and $D$. It not $A$ because $x\neq \frac 12$. Hence I have $50 \%$ to find the correct answer: or it is into $C$ (exact answer) or $E$ (none of the previous answers are correct).

> Any of you users see something else in your minds?

Comment: I think you mistyped the last sentence: you presumably didn't want to say D but E (previously having labelled the last answer by E). I can see people are trying to prove to you that D is not a solution - which you have already spotted!

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ops...I have done a mistake....thankkkkkk youuu. Now I edit my question thank you again very much.

Comment: $x=3$ satisfies the inequality, so $A,B,D$ are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can’t be D as

$$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{|x^2-1|-3}{1-2x}= \infty$$

Therefore for large negative values of $x$, $\frac{|x^2-1|-3}{1-2x}$ will be positive and the requested inequality can’t be satisfied. This allows to drop down option D that contains the interval $(-\infty,-1)$.

Comment: Why do you consider the $\lim$? Is there a true valid reason? Can you, please, explain better your answer. In meantime +1.

Comment: I consider limits because it is easy to evaluate for fraction maps.

Comment: What do you mean? This methodology never done in my life. Could you please add a few more specific details so that I can improve my knowledge?

Comment: What do I need to clarify better? The computation of the limit (which requires some knowledge on rational fractions)? Or why the value $\infty$ for the limit allows to drop down option D?

Comment: Because the value $∞$ for the limit allows to drop down option $D$ comparated with all the inequality: $\frac{|x^2-1|-3}{1-2x}<\:x$.What is essentially the usefulness of the limit? Obviously if I study the function at the first member I observe if it respects the inequality with respect to the graph $g(x)=x$.

Comment: See update in my answer.

Comment: Approved and thank you very much with kindness.

Answer (score 1):

On one hand, the perfectionist in me shudders. On the other hand, you have reduced the probability that your "random" guess would be wrong from $80\%$ to $50\%$ (which is not by a small amount - well done!), all by using a few simple but sound mathematical arguments. It is a bit of gaming the system, but unless teachers abandon using the multiple-choice-question tests in favour of old-fashioned questions ("Find the set of solutions of the inequality ... Show your reasoning.") which are *way* harder to mark, the system is there to be gamed, I suppose.

Comment: As written in my last questions I am helping a university student of Economics and Finance who does not have the appropriate knowledge. I wonder what some of the questions included in his tests will be used for in his field.

Comment: @Sebastiano I see where you are coming from. I think it is great that you have shown the student that some problems can be efficiently solved with right ideas, rather than blindly following the rules. ("Thinking outside the box"). I do think that the student should *also* know how to solve the same problem "the long way", as (1) Sometimes the right idea just does not come to mind, and (2) Doing things in a methodical and pedantic way is a useful skill (attitude, anyways) in itself, and likely useful for the student's future job, where omissions will cost real money. My 2p.